# Проверка JSON

Tags: gson, java, json, servlet

Всем добрый день. Помогите разобраться.
Есть json:

```
{"length":"6" ,"width":"20" ,"height":"25" ,"count":"30" }
```

Он у меня проходит нормально и без происшествий (перевариваю его на сервлете как один из параметров запроса). Но если например в ключе "`length`" - недописать букву или наоборот дописать, - то остальные параметры проходят нормально, а этот со значением **0**. То есть тоже всё хорошо, но неверное значение. Почему проходит такой вариант?! Разве

```
DetailSimply_json detail = json.fromJson(JsonString, DetailSimply_json.class);
```

Не должен тогда вылетать с Exception-ом каким-то? Или подобные проверки нужно делать ручками?

Comment: @dimchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Мой модуль телепатии подсказывает, что для десериализации JSON в объект вы пользуетесь библиотекой Gson, а `DetailSimply_json` - ваш кастомный класс, поле `length` которого имеет числовой тип. Воспроизвести вашу ситуацию мне не удалось, следующий код исправно бросает `NumberFormatException`:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String json = "{\"number\": \"X\", \"text\": \"text\"}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public static class Data {
        int number;
        String text;

        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

Это наталкивает на мысль о [кастомном десериализаторе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253238/gson-numberformatexception) для числовых значений, который был зарегистрирован при создании экземпляра парсера. Проверьте, откуда вы берёте десериализатор `json`, и не производится ли там его дополнительная настройка.

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще. Десериализатор использует в качестве дефолтного значения при отсутствии поля значения заданные дефолтным конструктором класса, то есть конструктором без параметров. Дефолтный конструктор, как известно, существует неявно или явно всегда. Неявный инициализирует все поля `0/null` - cоответственно вам надо рученьками создать дефолтный конструктор и там прописать значение поля `length` иже с ними:

```
public DetailSimply_json() {
   length=1;
   width=-1; 
   height=0;
   //и т.д.
}
```

Тогда, десериализатор при ошибке десериализации будет использовать заданные в конструкторе поля.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, теория хорошая, но, к сожалению, неверная (как минимум для последней версии Gson). Вот [мой код][1] для проверки. Если в строке `json` вместо `X` поставить число, всё работает, если же текст - вылетает `NumberFormatException`.

  [1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4dV0peiHnuMNzl0UzVpREk3dDg&authuser=0

Comment: @fori1ton, использую тотже вариант, и коректно выбрасывает NumberFormatException

Comment: @fori1ton, извеняюсь за некоректно поставленный вопрос. Вы правы, использую Gson. С значением {\"X\"}  разобралса, но если в самом стринге json вместо "number" написать "numberrrr" - тоесть сам ключ неверно написан, то перехват можна сделать только вариантом, как указал @Barmaley, руками прописать дефолтные значения, а потом уже сам обект проверять на валидные значения. Тоесть, если встретитса гдето в параметрах "-1"(нет такой длины) - то дальше обект обрабатыватса небудет. Можна, как-то обработать некоректный ключ в Gson, и не делать проверку уже екземпляра класа?